# Data management in matlab versus other common analysis packages

Tags: matlab, memory, object, memory-management, analysis

Background:

I am analyzing large amounts of data using an object oriented composition structure for sanity and easy analysis. Often times the highest level of my OO is an object that when saved is about 2 gigs. Loading the data into memory is not an issue always, and populating sub objects then higher objects based on their content is much more java memory efficient than just loading in a lot of mat files directly.

The Problem:

Saving these objects that are > 2 gigs will often fail. It is a somewhat well known problem that I have gotten around by just deleting a number of sub objects until the total size is below 2-3 gigs. This happens regardless of how boss the computer is, a 16 gigs of ram 8 cores etc, will still fail to save the objects correctly. Back versioning the save also does not help

Questions:

Is this a problem that others have solved somehow in MATLAB? Is there an alternative that I should look into that still has a lot of high level analysis and will NOT have this problem?

Questions welcome, thanks.

Comment: How do you save? Do you implement your own 'loadobj' and 'saveobj' methods? If no, you maybe want to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure this will help, but here: Do you make sure to use recent version of mat file? Check for instance [save](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/save.html). Quoting from the page:

*'-v7.3'    7.3 (R2006b) or later   Version 7.0 features plus **support for data items greater than or equal to 2 GB on 64-bit systems**.*

*'-v7'  7.0 (R14) or later  Version 6 features plus data compression and Unicode character encoding. Unicode encoding enables file sharing between systems that use different default character encoding schemes.*

Also, could by any chance your object by or contain a graphic handle object? In that case, it is wise to use [hgsave](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/hgsave.html)

Comment: I do use the most recent version. None of it has a handle graphic object, but the fact that hgsave exists makes me think @Jonas comment is important: Implementing my own save might help.

Comment: Can you tell us of your findings if you solve your problem this way? Oop and MATLAB is in the puzzling zone for me. Best

Comment: I will, implementing my own objsave and objload are next on my todo list.

Comment: In case you were wondering, my quick fix has turned into my solution, I just made a loadMyObj that takes a folder and stitches together the contents to make one large object in memory... It is actually pretty stable so I haven't needed to make anything better yet.